# how to store many arrays to one key

Tags: javascript, arrays, key, associative

I just get starting learning JS recently. Now I came across the problem and could not find blogs or tutorial to help very much or I did not get their points!

My problems is how to store many arrays to one key:
[image]

My code here:

```
let lines = fs.readFileSync(inGff).toString().split("\n");
 ...
 let column = lines[i].toString().split("\t");
 id = clpP1_69910 or clpP1_54343 or clpP1_69554 ...
 obj[id] = column; //only work for one key to one array.
```

In fact. I can do it simply with Perl:

```
push @{$obj{$id}}, [@info]
```

Not sure if there is a similar utility or more advanced in JS. Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dv6Ca.jpg)

Comment: `Object[key] = [Array, AnotherArray, MoreArray]`

Comment: `Object[key] = []; Object[key].push( column );`

Comment: thanks you all. the problem was solved finally!
if(Object[key] === undefined){
   Object[key] = [];
}

Object[key].push(column);

Answer (score 0):

You can store arrays inside objects like so:

---

```js
let data = {};

let keys = ['clpP1_69910', 'clpP1_69915', 'clpP1_69920', 'clpP1_69925'];

// Iterate keys
keys.forEach(el => {
  let arr = [];

  // Iterate to push array items
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    arr.push(i);
  }

  // Assign array to key
  data[el] = arr;

  // Clear array
  arr = null;
});

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

### Keys can store any type of value

To solve this you should set `clpP1_69910` to an empty `Array` and `.push` to the array when you add a column.

```
obj[clpP1_69910] = []
const lines = fs.readFileSync(inGff).toString().split('\n')
const columns = lines.map(line => line.toString().split('\t'))

columns.forEach(column => obj[clpP1_69910].push(column))
```

Or, the short version:

```
obj[clpP1_69910] = fs.readFileSync(inGff).toString().split('\n').map(line => line.toString().split('\t')).reduce((acc, cur) => acc.concat(cur), [])
```

The last part, the `.reduce` section, flattens the array of arrays, returning all the columns.